# Next step in solving an equations...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have managed so far to break down an the following equation:

$x^n+y^n=1$

to

$x^n=1-y^n$

but what is the next step to get $x$ on it's own?

*I have hopped over here from StackOverflow where I am trying draw [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) where a and b are always 1. So applogies for my lack of terminology! I have a very beginner understanding of mathematics and almost no understanding of mathematical notation for equations!*

Comment: Hint: try the n-th root of each side? Try it with $n = 2$ and then generalize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x^n+y^n=1$$
$$\iff x^n = 1 - y^n$$

$$\implies \large (x^n)^{\frac 1n} = x = \left(1 - y^n\right)^{\frac 1n}$$

Another way of expressing "to the $1/n$th power" is "the nth root of", which is denoted on the right-hand side below:

$$x = \left(1 - y^n\right)^{\large \frac 1n} = \sqrt[\Large n]{1 - y^n}$$

Comment: Factastic thank you!. The ⟺ symbol is new to me. What is it called so I may google it?

Comment: @Ross http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if

Comment: It's used to denote, e.g., "if and only if": it is usually called the "biconditional". $P \iff Q$ is equivalent to $[(P\implies Q)\;\text{and}\; (Q \implies P)]$

Comment: @amWhy: Looks spot on to me +1